# How to sign in in wkhtmltopdf to convert page of website that requires login

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, wkhtmltopdf

I hope you can help with this issue, 
I'm trying to use wkhtmltopdf tool, it works fine with regular website, but I tried to use it with edx, it came out with error, I suspect the issue is that it requires login with email with password, I do have email and password, but wkhtmltopdf tool doesn't have a command to login.

Could you help me out here?

I tried to login in first in the browser and used wkhtmltopdf tool
I tried to login in first with edx-dl tool and used wkhtmltopdf

Please do not give vague general solution, show your specific code or command line with example.

Thanks

Comment: You can login first with some other web-scraping type tool, then pass the cookie to `wkhtmltopdf` so it loads the page as an authenticated user. See the documentation here: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: Please do not give vague general solution, show your specific code or command line with example.
If you cannot or do not want to give an example and show line command and how it is done, then please let other help out
Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with scrapers in the Windows/PowerShell ecosystem, and I don't have a Windows machine to prototype on, so I cannot easily give specifics. That's why this suggestion is in the form of a comment, and not an answer. I just hope it helps point you in a workable direction.

Comment: Thanks for trying out, but it wasn’t helpful. I hope someone will shed the light with a specific example on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with `curl` with a sequence like this:

```
curl -c cookie.txt -XPOST 'http://example.com/login_route' \
  -d "email=myemail@example.com&password=mypassword" && \
  wkhtmltopdf \
    --cookie $(awk 'END {print $(NF-1), $NF}' cookie.txt) \
    'http://example.com/protected_route' output.pdf
```

The `$(awk 'END {print $(NF-1), $NF}' cookie.txt)` part gets the last two values out of cookie.txt, and passes them as a cookie key and value to `wkhtmltopdf`.

You might need to more processing to extract the needed cookie names and values if your app returns multiple cookies.

I'm not certain Windows has `curl` or `awk` installed, so you may need to substitute with whatever you have on hand to retrieve the cookie, and pass that to `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: I've got this error: C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -c cookie.txt -XPOST 'https://courses.edx.org/login' \ -d "email=xx@xxx.com&password=xxxx" && \ wkhtmltopdf \ --cookie $(awk 'END {print $(NF-1), $NF}' cookie.txt) "https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+7.05x+2T2019/courseware/bf81584e015d43aab58c88fddade343d/40e5602f86a44b8e93ef15d5a886296d/2?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMITx%2B7.05x%2B2T2019%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4046ec35e05e644758a3590748d3910434" C:/edx-dl-master/Downloaded/x.pdf
curl: (1) Protocol "'https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I hope you can help more.

Comment: I fixed the two error, after applying this line: curl -c cookie.txt -XPOST "https://courses.edx.org/login" / -d "email=xx@xx.com&password=xxxx" && / wkhtmltopdf / --cookie $(awk "END {print $(NF-1), $NF}" cookie.txt) "https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:MITx+7.05x+2T2019/courseware/bf81584e015d43aab58c88fddade343d/40e5602f86a44b8e93ef15d5a886296d/2?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMITx%2B7.05x%2B2T2019%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4046ec35e05e644758a3590748d3910434" C:/edx-dl-master/Downloaded/xxx.pd                                        But then I got this error:  curl: (3) <url> malformed

Comment: @Adam I think you'll need to specify http or https in the url like `https://courses.edx.org/login`. Also the back-slashes in my command aren't needed, it just makes it easier to read multi-line. The `&&` makes it so the `wkhtmltopdf` command runs after the curl finishes, but you can separate them into two commands if it helps you debug.

Comment: Thank you for this note, I tried it, and I got this error:  <p>You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a &#39;Referer header&#39; to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
  <p>If you have configured your browser to disable &#39;Referer&#39; headers, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for HTTPS connections, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>

Comment: @Adam Then add a referrer: `curl <other args> --referer 'https://courses.edx.org'`

Comment: I tried it, I've got the same previous error, I want to try docker, could you help me out here? I already installed docker on windows.